# Generic Crud in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a lot of tables and almost of them i have just to save or delete them without another query.
So I use `spring data jpa` like this :

```
 public interface SecteurAlerteRepository extends 
     JpaRepository<SecteurAlerte, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<SecteurAlerte>
     { }
```

But i have to cretae a lot of interface about 50 ones and it's too much !!

there is not a generic way to use just standard query CRUD in Spring data or in a other way ?

Comment: you can create a interface for your entities, for example IEntity and to extend the JpaRepository using the interface, ex: interface GenericRepository extends JpaRepository<IEntity, Integer>

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in Spring Data. The inner mechanics of Spring Data need the type parameters from the interface definition and if there is no interface definition with specific type parameters only the bound of the type parameters (`Object` in case of doubt) is available which is not usable.